# Adding HTML to folium popup in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I want to put HTML formatting into a folium map popup. How do I format the html popup inside my `for` loop?

My code:

```
import folium
import pandas
from folium import IFrame

data=pandas.read_csv("addresses.txt")
lat=list(data["LAT"])
lon=list(data["LON"])
name=list(data["NAME"])
desc=list(data["DESCRIPTION"])

map=folium.Map(location=[40.748817,73.985429],zoom_start=14,tiles="stamenterrain")
#folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron').add_to(map)

for lt,ln,nm,ds in zip(lat,lon,name,desc):
    test = folium.Html('<b>nm<br>desc</b>', script=True)
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt,ln],radius=6,color='grey',fill_color='yellow',
popup=test))

map.add_child(fg)
map.save("Map1.html")
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question but consider looping over data directly and extracting each value from the resulting row/series. Embrace pandas instead of tearing the DataFrame into lists.

Answer (score 2):

`folium` should handle this correctly by default.

As per the example docs:

```
import folium
import branca 

m = folium.Map([43, -100], zoom_start=4)

html = """
    <h1> This popup is an Iframe</h1><br>
    With a few lines of code...
    <p>
    <code>
        from numpy import *<br>
        exp(-2*pi)
    </code>
    </p>
    """

iframe = branca.element.IFrame(html=html, width=500, height=300)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=500)

folium.Marker([30, -100], popup=popup).add_to(m)
```

So in your example

```
for lt,ln,nm,ds in zip(lat,lon,name,desc):
    test = folium.Html('<b>nm<br>desc</b>', script=True) # i'm assuming this bit runs fine
    iframe = branca.element.IFrame(html=test, width=350, height=150)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, parse_html=True)
    folium.Marker(location=[lt,ln],radius=6,color='grey',fill_color='yellow', popup=popup)).add_to(map)
```